# Read in multi-level, complicated dictionary from text file in Python?

Tags: python

I am given a text file containing the print-out of a multi-level python dictionary. What is an easy way of loading it back to Python as "dictionaries in a dictionary", preserving the hierarchy?

```
{"options":{"version":2,"background":{"enable":"color","enableVR":false,"uid":"51af6a870cce449eb75b0345feebaebb","color":[0.06666666666666667,0.06666666666666667,0.06666666666666667]},"environment":{"uid":"d348dfd2a8104ab0b8528f885d645eb3","enable":false,"exposure":2.1402,"rotation":0,"blur":0.1,"backgroundExposure":1,"shadowEnable":false,"shadowBias":0.005},"lighting":{"enable":true,"lights":[{"type":"DIRECTION","enable":true,"color":[0.7806122448979592,0.7985214493960848,1],"intensity":0.96,"ground":[0.3,0.2,0.2],"intensityGround":1,"matrix":[-0.9815804500275482,0.1909922167095499,-0.004668327333101102,0,0.13548347102422797,0.7131126062169096,0.6878332937084056,0,0.13469984856318096,0.6745312327912614,-0.7258536813891331,0,0.2764793650767136,1.078885802792896,13.000759350324298,1],"falloff":1.187541845331568,"attachedToCamera":true,"angle":45,"hardness":0.5,"castShadows":true,"shadowBias":0.005,"shadowSize":1024},{"type":"DIRECTION","enable":true,"color":[1,0.8783319450229073,0.7091836734693877],"intensity":1,"ground":[0.3,0.2,0.2],"intensityGround":1,"matrix":[0.7755211495104662,-0.0666602860002539,0.6277924441503967,0,0.2690483737361956,0.9344846523281437,-0.233133882464682,0,-0.5711216326246741,0.3497067926613838,0.7426474533145686,0,-0.747616034294845,0.6075892729952792,15.131447202854693,1],"falloff":1.187541845331568,"attachedToCamera":true,"angle":45,"hardness":0.5,"castShadows":true,"shadowBias":0.005,"shadowSize":1024},{"type":"HEMI","enable":true,"color":[0.423469387755102,0.7352665556018328,1],"intensity":0.12,"ground":[0.9642857142857143,0.6484128636877489,0.2607507288629738],"intensityGround":0.06,"matrix":[0.6903299131022926,-0.7076363669144057,-0.15064986988498263,0,-0.011089698239978026,0.19785137301620165,-0.9801692980238416,0,0.7234097246160907,0.6783108479272498,0.12873524736872857,0,1.1306543819885668,1.0843697482030679,14.240705446640208,1],"falloff":1.187541845331568,"attachedToCamera":false,"angle":45,"hardness":0.5,"castShadows":true,"shadowBias":0.005,"shadowSize":1024}]},"scene":{"fov":1,"nearFarRatio":0.005,"postProcess":{"enable":true,"grain":{"enable":false,"animated":false,"factor":0.15},"sharpen":{"enable":false,"factor":0.2},"chromaticAberration":{"enable":false,"factor":0.05},"vignette":{"enable":false,"lens":[0.8,0.25]},"bloom":{"enable":false,"factor":0.5,"threshold":0,"radius":0.7},"toneMapping":{"enable":false,"method":"default","exposure":1,"brightness":0,"contrast":0,"saturation":1},"colorBalance":{"enable":false,"low":[0,0,0],"mid":[0,0,0],"high":[0,0,0]},"dof":{"enable":false,"blurNear":0.5,"blurFar":0.5,"focusPoint":[0,0,0]},"ssao":{"enable":false,"bias":0.009068293352733361,"intensity":0.5,"radius":0.04534146676366681}}},"materials":{"d47e69e8-04c7-4b9a-a025-c86be71f6bb7":{"version":3,"stateSetID":0,"shadeless":false,"id":"d47e69e8-04c7-4b9a-a025-c86be71f6bb7","name":"human.001_0","cullFace":"DISABLE","reflection":0.1,"channels":{"DiffuseColor":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true},"DiffuseIntensity":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true},"SpecularColor":{"color":[0.5,0.5,0.5],"factor":0,"enable":true},"SpecularHardness":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":12.5,"enable":true},"Displacement":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0,"enable":true},"NormalMap":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false,"flipY":true},"BumpMap":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false},"Opacity":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true,"type":"alphaBlend","invert":false},"EmitColor":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0,"enable":true,"type":"additive"},"DiffusePBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true},"AlbedoPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false},"SpecularPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0.05,"enable":true},"GlossinessPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0.4,"enable":false},"RoughnessPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0.6,"enable":true},"MetalnessPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0,"enable":false},"SpecularF0":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0.5,"enable":false},"AOPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false,"occludeSpecular":false},"CavityPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false}}},"8d06432a-9927-4748-982c-d1b31d85d2ed":{"version":3,"stateSetID":1,"shadeless":false,"id":"8d06432a-9927-4748-982c-d1b31d85d2ed","name":"Material.001","cullFace":"DISABLE","reflection":0.1,"channels":{"DiffuseColor":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true},"DiffuseIntensity":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true},"SpecularColor":{"color":[0.5,0.5,0.5],"factor":0,"enable":true},"SpecularHardness":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":12.5,"enable":true},"Displacement":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0,"enable":true},"NormalMap":{"texture":{"magFilter":"LINEAR","minFilter":"LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR","wrapS":"REPEAT","wrapT":"REPEAT","textureTarget":"TEXTURE_2D","internalFormat":"RGB","texCoordUnit":0,"uid":"251c0badfd924b8a8cb08c087e6da38d"},"factor":1,"enable":true,"flipY":true},"BumpMap":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false},"Opacity":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true,"type":"alphaBlend","invert":false},"EmitColor":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0,"enable":true,"type":"additive"},"DiffusePBR":{"texture":{"magFilter":"LINEAR","minFilter":"LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR","wrapS":"REPEAT","wrapT":"REPEAT","textureTarget":"TEXTURE_2D","internalFormat":"RGB","texCoordUnit":0,"uid":"8eeb9ad270f444c192548d8a8e5a6976"},"factor":1,"enable":true},"AlbedoPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":false},"SpecularPBR":{"texture":{"magFilter":"LINEAR","minFilter":"LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR","wrapS":"REPEAT","wrapT":"REPEAT","textureTarget":"TEXTURE_2D","internalFormat":"RGB","texCoordUnit":0,"uid":"aa3aa7c807424fe09f6de04420200b45"},"factor":1,"enable":true},"GlossinessPBR":{"texture":{"magFilter":"LINEAR","minFilter":"LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR","wrapS":"REPEAT","wrapT":"REPEAT","textureTarget":"TEXTURE_2D","internalFormat":"LUMINANCE","texCoordUnit":0,"uid":"e26b58d50de146909143ca2fb94ce1f4"},"factor":1,"enable":true},"RoughnessPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0.20000000298023224,"enable":false},"MetalnessPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0,"enable":false},"SpecularF0":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":0.5,"enable":false},"AOPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true,"occludeSpecular":false},"CavityPBR":{"color":[1,1,1],"factor":1,"enable":true}}}},"orientation":{"matrix":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]},"camera":{"position":[-0.11948612417396776,-3.244330914375282,-200.12585703226537],"target":[0.015371265170614823,0.11829936504364014,14.100300312042236]},"animation":{"order":[],"speed":1,"cycleMode":"one","autoplay":false},"hotspot":{"hotspots":[]},"vr":{"scale":0.9068293352733361,"initialCamera":{"position":[0.08103972646236413,-2.0762001369882364,13.491239980506897],"rotation":[0,0,0,1]},"floorHeight":13.491239980506897},"shading":{"pointSize":2,"type":"lit","renderer":"pbr","vertexColor":{"enable":false,"useAlpha":false,"colorSpace":"srgb"}},"wireframe":{"enable":false,"color":"000000FF"}}}
```

I'm thinking about rule-based parsing, but that would be horrendously complicated.

Comment: What you have there looks like JSON, no? Have you tried using [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: `import json; d = "<text_file_contents>"; myd = json.loads(d)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe true! thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to go about this in this case would be to load the string into a JSON parser. This will return you the object you need. Please use the following code (where `'filename'` is the name of the file that holds your original string).

```
import json
with open('filename') as file:
    myString = file.read()
myJSON = json.loads(myString)
```

The `myJSON` object is now a dictionary:

```
>>> myJSON['options']['version']
2
```

Comment: Note that you should generally use the `with` context manager to open a file, and variable names should be `snake_case`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe interesting about snake case. Is there a reason why Python prefers snake case to camel case? I in general like using camel case, as I reserve `_` as version separator. For example, I usually write `generateData` and `generateData_useModel` instead of `generate_data` and `generate_data_use_model` (do you think it's chaos here?)

Comment: @SibbsGambling I'm not sure what you mean by a "version" in this context but for the official Python style guide see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the tips! I haven't gone through and read the PEP8 yet.

Answer (score 1):

First read the file content into a string, like:

```
with open("thefile") as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Then simply use the `eval()` builtin:

```
thedict = eval(s)
```

For the specific string you gave, that will yield errors unless you first do, e.g.,

```
false, true = 0, 1
```

because `false` and `true` are used like variable names in the string.

Comment: This will work, but is clearly not the one (and preferably only one) way to do it. It contains `false` and `true` rather than `False` and `True` because it's JSON, not because they're variable names. If it was actually a Python print out it would also use single quotes by default, whereas JSON requires double quotes.

Comment: It looks that way to me too, but the OP said it's a "print-out of a multi-level python dictionary".  If they only had 10 rep, I'd be more inclined to assume they were confused about that - as is, I'm taking them at their word -)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about stupidly describing JSON format as a "print-out of a multi-level python dictionary"!